# How to fix react framework error in GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, github

I'm learning React and setup a repo in Github, which is located at https://github.com/chenjianAgain/ContactManager_Source.git.

I use npm run build to generate a directory of build in my laptop. And serve build works OK.

But when I copy the entire build dir to the new repo below, it can't be visited by Github Pages. https://github.com/chenjianAgain/ContactManager_Destination.git.

Can anybody be kind to help me?
Many thanks.

https://github.com/chenjianAgain/ContactManager_Source.git.

The source code works well on my laptop.

`serve build` also works well on my laptop.

https://github.com/chenjianAgain/ContactManager_Destination.git.

But when I copy all files from /build to the repo above, the Github Pages doesn't work.

Comment: And I serve the static website on GCP, it seems to work well. http://34.73.6.184/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your package.json and add this property

```
    "homepage": "http://username.github.io/myapp"
```

My guess is that you missed this step.

Also, if you're using react-router you are going to have to add a basename if you are using a subdirectory on your application.

```
    <BrowserRouter basename="/myapp">
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
```